# How to enable the Mongoose Update Validator - Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Here is my schema:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 3,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    number: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 8,
        required: true
    }
})
```

My update code:

```
app.put('/api/persons/:id', (request, response, next) => {
const body = request.body
const person = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number
}

let opts = {
    runValidators: true
};

Person.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, { new: true }, opts)
    .then(updatedPerson => {
        response.json(updatedPerson)
    })
    .catch(error => next(error))})
```

I try to update the information, and the validation does not work with update, it works when create a new Person. I know Mongoose Update Validator are off by default, I have tried many ways to enable it, however, it does not work, could anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

place your options in the third params:

```
Person.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, { new: true, runValidators: true })
```